# change date format in glue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a dataset that looks like this. I want to change all values from the date column to proper date time format. dd-mm-2020 (and preferably also arrange all rows in an ascending order according to the date if possible). How can I achieve this in spark?

```
Name   |Type        |   date      |Value    |
ALZA CZ|New         | 01/01(FRI)  |     0
CLPA CZ|New         | 01/01(FRI)  |     1
ALZA CZ|Old         | 01/02(SAT)  |     1
CLPA CZ|Old         | 01/02(SAT)  |     5
```

The datasource is already converted into a dataframe:

```
dataframe = datasource0.toDF()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you can use `regexp_replace` (Python docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html?highlight=regexp_replace)) to change the String of the `Date` column, which takes 3 arguments: the column to operate on, the regular expressions of what you want to match, and what you want to replace the matched text with.

As for the date ascending sort, you need to convert the `Date` column into `DateType`. For that you can use the `to_date` method (Python docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html?highlight=to_date#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date)). However, this will inevitably change your date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` ("that's because, as you'd guess, in ascending order we first look at sorting by year, then by month, and lastly by day to have 2019 come *before* 2020, then January come *before* February, and the 1st of the month to come *before* its 2nd). To handle this, we simply use the `date_format` method (Python docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html?highlight=date_format#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format)) **after ordering the rows by the date** to specify the desired date format that we want to put out.

To test this, I added some rows in your `dataframe`:

```
+-------+----+----------+-----+
|   Name|Type|      Date|Value|
+-------+----+----------+-----+
|ALZA CZ| New|01/01(FRI)|    0|
|CLPA CZ| New|01/01(FRI)|    1|
|YYYY YY| Old|01/29(FRI)|    1|
|ALZA CZ| Old|01/02(SAT)|    1|
|XXXX XX| New|03/12(SAT)|    5|
|CLPA CZ| Old|01/02(SAT)|    5|
+-------+----+----------+-----+
```

And then we use the methods from above to convert `Date` to what we need . Here I did the regex matching in two steps, one to replace the `/` between month and date to `-` and one to replace the text with the parentheses with `-2020`. Next, I just converted `Date` into a `DateType` column (by specifying the current `MM-dd-yyyy` date format) and ordered the DataFrame rows accordingly, before I converted `Date` one last time for the desired `dd-MM-yyyy` String format.

```
// In Python
dataframe.withColumn("Date", regexp_replace("Date", "/", "-"))
          .withColumn("Date", regexp_replace("Date", "\\([a-z]+\\)", "-2020"))
          .withColumn("Date", to_date("Date", "MM-dd-yyyy"))
          .orderBy("Date")
          .withColumn("Date", date_format("Date", "dd-MM-yyyy"))


// In Scala
dataframe.withColumn("Date", regexp_replace(col("Date"), "/", "-"))
          .withColumn("Date", regexp_replace(col("Date"), "\\([A-Z]+\\)", "-2020"))
          .withColumn("Date", to_date(col("Date"), "MM-dd-yyyy"))
          .orderBy("Date")
          .withColumn("Date", date_format(col("Date"), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

The manipulated `dataframe` now looks like this:

```
+-------+----+----------+-----+
|   Name|Type|      Date|Value|
+-------+----+----------+-----+
|CLPA CZ| New|01-01-2020|    1|
|ALZA CZ| New|01-01-2020|    0|
|ALZA CZ| Old|02-01-2020|    1|
|CLPA CZ| Old|02-01-2020|    5|
|YYYY YY| Old|29-01-2020|    1|
|XXXX XX| New|12-03-2020|    5|
+-------+----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: For some reason it gives me all "null" values in the final dataframe

Comment: Try without the last `withColumn` method. It might just be a PySpark thing for turning `DateType` to `String`

Comment: changing ```[A-Z]``` to ```[a-z]```seemed to fix the problem